# Linux debian 10 how to make a script run a program at startup and auto input value to this program console

Tags: linux, shell

Hello guys i'm learning about linux for myself and i wrote a program sample by python as below with filename as "sample_login" at "/home/user/Desktop/sample_login"

```
ID = Input("ID: ")
print (ID)
pw = Input("PW: ")
print (pw)
```

Now i want to make a shell script that could change to this program directory and run my program and input id and pw automatically to program console after reboot then how could i do it?i mean perform command as below

```
cd /home/user/Desktop
./sample_login
#wait ID: 
#input user_id
...
```

Thank you guys so much

Answer (score 3):

In order to run a script at boot up, you can use [systemd](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html) service files.

sample.service:

```
[Unit]
Description=sample service

[Service]
User=johndoe
WorkingDirectory=/path/to/working_dir/
ExecStart=/path/to/working_dir/your_script
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

You just need to move this file to `/etc/systemd/system/.` and enable it with `systemctl enable sample.service` so it starts at bootup. Instead of expecting input, you could accept command line parameters that's a bit easier to handle in automated scripts.

Comment: Thank for your reply the reason i want to do by this way to learn shell script for my self and even i tried to search about the way to move /change directory by script i still can't understand it? :lol: am i too noob? btw could you please explain about " accept command line parameters" sorry but i'm learning about linux and trying to practice it via google cloud :-s so this term is new to me . Thank you

Comment: Maybe not what the OP wanted but still a good answer.  In addition to `WantedBy=`, one may also need to specify `After=` so that `your_script` is not executed before the system is ready for it.

Comment: @John1024 is there any way to make my shell script could read the output from python program and send a value to input ?

Comment: @Neosteam Instead of using `input()`, check out command line arguments for python scripts. It will make your life way easier. For example follow this guide to get started with command line arguments: https://realpython.com/python-command-line-arguments/. With that you can then just call `./sample_login user password` and it will enter the values.

Comment: @schilli yes i was searching about it and tried , it's working well but i still want to know is there any way to make a script likes that. Thank you so much